# which of 4 dc voltages is highest?

Tags: voltage-measurement

I need a simple circuit that will light one of 4 leds showing which of 4 dc voltages are the highest. This has to be a hardware soulution and voltages will be below 5 volts. So if one voltage is 2 volts and the others are less then the  2 volt line will light it's led and the others will be off.  If one line is 2.5 volts and the rest 2.1 the same thing.I'm Trying to make a non mechanical wind vane.

Comment: Why does it have to be a hardware solution?

Comment: Agreeing with finbarr here. This gets pretty easy with standard microcontrollers, but a four-way comparator... Not trivial, IMHO

Comment: This would take 10-15 minutes on an Arduino or something similar ...

Comment: Can I ask your reason for insisting on a hardware solution? As everyone has rightly said, this is what microcontrollers are very, very good at making very, very easy and cheap.

Comment: @TonyM last I checked a micro WAS a hardware solution.

Comment: @Trevor, now you're up and awake, attempted pedantry has gone up ten notches on this site :-) But check again, dear fellow: the MCU is a hardware implementation of a software solution; it's activity is determined by firmware. Place that in your pipe and ignite it...

Comment: @TonyM :) Ha Ha love it. I couldn't resist. :)  Still, once programmed a micro is nothing more than a fancy digital state machine or FPGA, especially for this kind of functionality. Folks seem to forget that.

Comment: @Trevor :-D My guess is that it's a skills thing, that the OP considers themselves hardware capable but not software capable. Were that to be the case, this'd be a great one for them to cut their teeth on. Could be approvals...

Comment: Your spec is also somewhat incomplete. What if two lines have, say, 2.5V and the other two have less? Should both LEDs light or neither?

Answer (score 3):

THE BAT-CAVE..... > XYZ Comparators

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR9eac.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**NOTE:** A,B,C and D need to be low impedance. If not you also need unity gain buffers on each line.

Comment: This is a better solution than mine! Didn't think of using diodes like that. I blame final exams frying my brain. Only downside is that the voltages have to be sufficient to be able to drive those diodes. A 0.2~0.3V drop in the diode could be significant, depending on the application.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could just use a bunch of logic and comparators. While I feel the best way to do this is to use a simple microcontroller, it is still possible to do without, so in the interest of answering the question posed:

The comparator is a fairly common circuit element. You can think of it as a differential amplifier with infinite (or otherwise very large) gain. This is similar to how an op amp is modelled, and indeed, comparators and op amps share so much in common that an op amp can be used as a comparator, and often is in cheap or hobbyist circuits. A comparator's output saturates high if its (+) input is greater than its (-) input, and it saturates low if its (-) input is greater than its (+) input. A true comparator should have these saturation voltages equal or very close to the supply rails, but op amps used as comparators typically do not, missing them by a margin of a volt or so (typically different on positive and negative sides).

This could be easily used to light an LED to indicate the higher of two voltages, but if you want to determine the highest of four, things get a little more complex, and you have to put multiple comparators together and then use some logic afterward. The more voltages involved, the more comparators and logic required. To demonstrate, here is the circuit to indicate the highest of two voltages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVufSI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, this will light D1 when A > B, and D2 when A < B. Simple enough. But if you want to introduce a third voltage, things get slightly more complicated. You'll need three comparators, one to compare A and B, one for B and C, and one for A and C; then, logic is used to determine which voltage is higher than both of the others, and the relevant LED is lit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTQsFP.png)</sup>

This circuit can determine which of three voltages is largest; D1 lights if A is largest, D2 lights if B is largest, and D3 lights if C is largest. (note: There is, in fact, a way to skip the AND gates in this! It only works in the three-voltage case, but think of connecting the diodes between comparator outputs, instead of to ground. This will only work if your comparators can both sink and source enough current to drive the LED.)

A four-voltage comparator would be essentially the same, but with more comparators; you'll need to compare every voltage to every other voltage, so the number of comparators needed in this case will be six. In general, for n voltages, you will need (n - 1)! comparators.

Answer (score 1):

This is another XY problem.

Weather direction encoders use two staggered rotary contacts with a quadrature pattern to encode any direction with desired resolution , e.g. 4,8,16 etc per rotation.

An "analog priority encoder/decoder is possible

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXePCj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but never done this way.  unless you have several reasons to use this method... like cost , performance , size? if so specify source impedance and voltage range vs wind pressure.

what if they are all 2.1V with almost no wind?

### simple solution

I cannot draw or move parts on schematic on iPad , but imagine a simple 20mA constant current sink, that works down to Vmin 2V?? and connected to the center of 4 cathodes, then the voltage on each direction will be significantly brighter with a 0.1V differential on any LED anode as long as the input load does not affect Vin with 20mA.

The 20mA CC can be a simple JFET with Vgs=0. This is much simpler than a PIC uC

> Only 1 JFET and 4 matched LEDs from same batch (easy)

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/fairchild-on-semiconductor/J111_D26Z/J111_D26ZTR-ND/1048975

If Vmin is <2V use GaAs RED LEDs which have Vf = 1.6V but less mcd brightness than AlGaAs ReD with Vf=2.0 to 2.2V. The JFET adds 30 Ohms

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get any simpler than this......

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxPNpB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Bonus Feature: Micro can integrate sensor levels to indicate predominant direction.

Notice I only used one resistor for the LEDs. Under the original OP's question only one LED is ever on at once... so one R is fine for that. Having one per LED would be beneficial though if the OP wanted to indicate SE, NW etc. by lighting two LEDs at once.

Comment: Yes, that's go to be the principle of the easiest idea. But why a shared resistor for the LED instead of a resistor per LED...are they so desperate to save 6p that they'll put up with varying brilliance on LEDs? (my guess is that you couldn't be asked to draw all 4 resistors :-) )

Comment: @TonyM under the original OP's question only one LED is ever on at once... so one R is fine for that. Having multiples would be beneficial though if the OP wanted to indicate SE, NW etc by lighting two LEDs at one. Hmm.. I think I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Aha - me being a pillock and not reading the question :-)

Comment: what is that chip with the 4 adc inputs?

Comment: @frenchie take your pick of one of a variety of cheap 8bit micros.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a mcu-based solution.

here is an example implementation. Inputs coming in on RA0..2, and outputs taking out on RC0..2, respectively.

Programming is simple:
[image]

You can obviously add some fancier features but it gets the job done:
[image]

all of that in 5 minutes.

Comment: You code a microcontroller using Ladder? Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftcvPl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @analogsystemsrfwhat is the reason for Q5? I'm assuming I1 is a constant current source.